# Compile mysqlclient on RHEL 7 and run on RHEL 6 (g++ on Linux)

Tags: c++, mysql, makefile

We have a business need to compile our software on one platform and deliver on another. This has been fine until we needed to compile towards the mysqlclient to connect to the database.

**I'm wondering if anyone else has attempted to compile towards mysqlclient and run on a separate machine with success.**

Some documentation we followed:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html

Ultimately, we've tried compiling and linking all sorts of different ways and get different errors based on what we try. The furthest we've got is fully compiling, but then running the program gives us something like this:

```
bin/myProgram: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14` not found (required by bin/myProgram)
```

Note that we've tried linking towards and delivering the libc.so.6 from the machine that was compiled on, but we still give errors like this, and it seems dangerous anyways to have multiple versions of some STL files in use.

Here's a Makefile for a sample small application we made that reproduces the issue:

```
$(TargetDir)/myProgram: $(OBJS)
  @ echo
  @ echo Linking myProgram
  @ g++ -I /work/mariadb-5.5.53/include \ # Tried various versions of MySQL
    $(OBJS) -o $@ -L/work/mariadb-5.5.53/libmysql -lmysqlclient
  @ echo Build complete!

$(TargetDir)/%.0 : %.C
  @ echo Compiling $(notdir $<)
  @ g++ -I /work/mariadb-5.5.53/include -o $@ -c $<
```

**EDIT: Our team took the suggestion of the accepted response below and compiled on RHEL 6 instead, and using that to deliver with. This has been successful and we are now able to move forward.**

How we compile with the above Makefile: $ make -s -C src

Comment: Generic answer: install a hypervisor, set up a VM that matches the target as closely as possible, compile there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if anyone else has attempted to compile towards mysqlclient and run on a separate machine with success.

People do that routinely.  It is the basis for packaging systems such as RPM.  People also do it for dissimilar systems, which is called "cross compiling".

What is not so common is compiling for a system with one version of a given OS and expecting the result to work on systems with *earlier* versions of that OS.  Under some circumstances that can work, but people who want to support multiple versions of an OS without separate compilation typically approach it by compiling for the *earlier* version, not the latter.  This presents fewer compatibility problems, and those that arise are usually easier to resolve.

> Note that we've tried linking towards and delivering the libc.so.6 from the machine that was compiled on, but we still give errors like this, and it seems dangerous anyways to have multiple versions of some STL files in use.

Delivering all the needed shared libraries together with the executable(s) is an alternative that may work -- and indeed may be required in conjunction with building for the earlier OS version instead of for the later, but it's not necessarily sufficient to just copy the shared library binaries from the build host.  The executable and the libraries on which it depends, recursively, all need to be dynamically linked at runtime to the right versions of their needed libraries.  It is not uncommon for these to be built in a way that does not provide for linking libraries from a non-standard path.

Another alternative is to perform all-static linking.  This produces (much) larger executables, but they have no dependencies on the host system's libraries.  Such binaries have a better chance of running on older versions of the target OS, though there are still potential issues with syscalls.

The most reliable alternative, at least for compiled software, is both build on the earliest OS you want to support and perform static linking.

If you are delivering a bunch of executables that use the same libraries, and you want to save space by using shared libraries, then it's still better to build on the earliest system you want to support, and package the result with the shared libraries for that OS version (which may involve tweaking or rebuilding some of the libs).

Comment: Our team has taken your advice and switched to compiling on RHEL 6. This has worked and we can now move forward. Thanks for your detailed response!